# What role do the composers of Halo's soundtracks have in the developmental processes of the Halo games?

Tags: halo

The Wikipedia page for *Halo 3* includes the following:

> Composer Martin O'Donnell recalled he did not feel the draft would work, as it left out previous characters and plot threads. Having recently seen the film Serenity, he insisted that characters should die to increase the stakes. Staten returned to do edits after the plot had been established.
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_3#Development)

There is also a mention of the creative team for *Halo 3*'s development being quite out of sorts, due to different members taking leaves of absence and such. However, it's gotten me thinking. **How much of a role do the composers of the Halo soundtracks**, specifically Martin O'Donnell and Michael Salvatori (the composers for the first Halo trilogy, *Halo 3: ODST*, and *Halo: Reach*), **have in the creative process of the Halo games?**

Comment: https://halo.bungie.org/misc/nico_marty_interview.html

Comment: I believe this question belongs either on arqade or the game development stack exchange sites.